# Creating automated uninstall script in Perl

Tags: perl

Could someone please show me an example of how I could do the following:

If I use a shell command to generate a two list of packages, for e.g:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i packages1
and
rpm -qa | grep -i packages2
```

rather than using yum to "manually" uninstall each of the packages shown in the generated list, is there a way to placed them into a Perl loop to automatically do this?

Comment: Does it have to be in perl? Could you just pipe it through xargs to run the yum uninstall command for each package?

Comment: Try `rpm -qa | grep -E 'packages|packages2' | xargs rpm -e`

Comment: Hi, thanks for that cool command, but yeah unfortunatley I need it in perl :(

Comment: If you absolutely need a perl expression, `system "rpm -qa | grep -i -E 'packages|packages2' | xargs rpm -e";` does quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do command line processing in Perl, I recommend [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun).

```
use IPC::Run qw(run);
my $regex = join '|', map { quotemeta } @packages;
run ['rpm', '-qa'], '|', ['egrep', $regex], '|', ['xargs', 'yum', '-y', 'remove'];
```